# Does Bootstrap 3 really use @screen-md-min in its own Less files?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

On this page http://getbootstrap.com/css/, it appears that Bootstrap 3 uses variables such as `@screen-md-min`.

However, I downloaded its source files, searched all its Less files, and am unable to find it.

Did I miss something? In which Less file does @screen-md-min appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this variables in the following files:

- variables.less
- mixins.less
- grid.less
- responsive-utilities.less

Comment: Thanks for your input. Are you able to find the use of @screen-md-min in any of the Less files you mentioned?

Comment: I added responsive-utilities.less in this file the variable is used to define a min-width for some media queries.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 3.0.2. I am unable to find any use of @screen-md-min in responsive-utilities.less. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I use the same bootstrap version. bootstrap-3.0.2\less\responsive-utilities.less line 38, 59, 81, 103, 123, 144, 16 and 188.

Comment: you are right. That variable is used in all the Less files you listed. My bad. I made a mistake. I was under the impression that I am using Bootstrap 3.0.2 (which I am using for another project), but I was actually using Bootstrap 3.0.0, which does not have this variable. Many thanks!

Comment: Great news, success with your project!